# Best way to replace a Item in a List by ID

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class

I have a simple class with one ID and multiple other properties

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

now I have a `List<Item>` with lots of these Items

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item() { ID = 1, Prop1="foo" , Prop2= "foo" },
    new Item() { ID = 2, Prop1="foo" , Prop2= "foo" },
    new Item() { ID = 3, Prop1="foo" , Prop2= "foo" }
};
```

Question: When I want to replace a `Item` with a newer version by its ID, is there a better/smater way than this:

```
//new Item
Item replacement = new Item() { ID = 2, Prop1 = "bar", Prop2 = "bar" };

items.RemoveAll(x => x.ID == replacement.ID);
items.Add(replacement);
items = items.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to do a full replacement and not just an update (you could simply find the object, and copy properties one by one), you can save yourself a bit of trouble by finding its index and then replacing it directly, rather than removing, adding, and reordering.

```
int index = items.FindIndex(item => item.ID == replacement.ID);
if (index >= 0)
{
    items[index] = replacement;
}
```

The replacement will be in the same spot as the original.

Comment: what if there are multiple records with same ID and OP want to replace all those records? Here in your answer you are just getting single index where `item.ID == replacement.ID` is true. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Prasad, The wording of his question leads me to believe that that the ID identifies a single, unique record. If that's a wrong assumption, then it requires clarification (and with little effort, this could be turned into a loop).

Answer (score 0):

- Since you're ordering your list, you can also use a binary sort to find the indexes to remove and add.
- There's also no need to both add & remove it. You could find the item and change its properties. Saving you the remove & order operations.
- If you have a lot of items, using a Dictionary with the Id as key will give you faster lookups. The Id has to be unique in that case.

Comment: The OP use of `RemoveAll` suggests Id is not unique within the List. If that turns out to be wrong and the ID is unique, than That's probably the best way to do it.

Comment: You're right, for a dictionary, the key has to be unique. Using a binary should still work.

Comment: The use of an ID field would tend to indicate uniqueness, in my opinion. It's an assumption I would make given the wording of the question, as well.